# Poincaré's quote: "I thought a lot about them"

Tags: mathematicians, quote

I have a vague memory of reading once that somebody (maybe a journalist) asked Poincaré how had he been capable of solving all those fantastically difficult problems that he had solved. The answer was simply “I thought a lot about them”.

Has anyone more details about this history? I hope that it is not just a product of my imagination.

Comment: Poincare delivered a lecture to the *Societe de Psychologie* in Paris, published as an essay [Mathematical Creation](https://archive.org/details/jstor-27900262/page/n1/mode/2up), detailing exactly how he thought a lot about them and reflecting on how he thought it worked, so this sounds anecdotal.

Comment: A similar thought is credited to Isaac Newton, "By always thinking unto them . I keep the subject constantly before me , and wait till the first dawnings open slowly by little and little into a full and clear light " .   Poincaré might have been quoting Newton.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Of course tracking down where (& if) Newton said this is another question.  It seems to have been popularized by F. Nietzsche, who read it in Biot's biography of Newton.

Comment: @kimchilover In fact, Wikiquote doesn't even mention it.

Comment: Indirectly, thru https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_Henry_Lewes (search for Newton on that page)